# Does inter-pixel distance change after downsampling?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, signal-processing, sift

I have a question. So I am trying to implement SIFT(Scale Invariance Feature Transform)  paper by Prof. David Lowe.

My question is regarding inter-pixel distance. I think after downsampling the number of pixels change(since an image represented by a matrix will be reduced to a lower size in each dimension after subsampling) but the inter-pixel distance remains the same. But I am reading the paper '[Anatomy of SIFT](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/82/article.pdf)' which states that after downsampling(subsampling) by 2 the inter-pixel distance doubles.

Am I missing something? Can someone correct my understanding?
Thanks!

Comment: If your image records the same scene but suddenly has half as many pixels across, it stands to reason the pixels must be twice as wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, in uncalibrated coordinates the pixel inter-distance is 1.

In calibrated coordinates, the distance depends on the sampling rate and increases with downsampling.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the reply. Can you provide links to some resources where I can read up more on this? Thanks!